# Aviation regulation in Liechtenstein, Dominica and Tuvalu?

Tags: aviation, switzerland

I have understood that both Liechtenstein, Dominica and Tuvalu are not members of [ICAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization). I have also read that Liechtenstein have delegated the application of treaty to Switzerland.

My question is the following:

- Is correct my assumption that the aviation regulation and authority in Liechtenstein is provided by Switzerland?
- What is the applicable regulation at Dominica and Tuvalu?

Comment: Have you asked at [Aviation SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com)? Much more likely to have the expertise you'd need.

Comment: Actually they directed me here.

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully one of the experts there will follow and provide an answer, I don't think anybody has particular specialty in aviation law around here, though.

Answer (score 1):

[ICAO](http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/chicago.pdf) claims that Switzerland claimed that Liechtenstein claimed that "this Convention will be applicable to the territory of the Principality as well as to that of the Swiss Confederation, as long as the Treaty of 29 March 1923 integrating the whole territory of Liechtenstein with the Swiss customs territory will remain in force". (Balzers Airport (LSXB) at the edge of Liechtenstein 47.068121°, 9.481371° is a heliport).

Answer (score -1):

The [Pacific Aviation Safety Office](http://www.paso.aero) is responsible for numbers island nations in the Pacific, including Tuvalu.

The [Eastern Caribbean Civil Aviation Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Caribbean_Civil_Aviation_Authority) is responsible for overseeing nations in the Organization of Eastern Caribbean States, which includes Dominica.

I can't find much information for Lichtenstein, and that's reasonable since Lichtenstein doesn't have any airfield.

Comment: That is answering the first question (for Tuvalu and Dominica) who is the authority responsible. But not about the regulation, as those are associations not signed regulations. For Lichtenstein the other answer solved it properly.